Please, answer like an expert! Upvotes *and* downvotes are critical during this time
I'm already seeing a flood of low-quality and outright wrong answers to my questions get posted within seconds, and worse they are getting voted up. It's worse than the rep rush I'm used to from StackOverflow!
At this point, we should be focused on good questions and the best answers. These are the answers that are going to serve as the standard for the public beta questions. Don't just throw out one line and a Google link or "well, I think X"! You're LEGO experts; give expert-quality answers.
Please do not be afraid to downvote; wrong answers and bad policies now will plague the site forever.

And, askers, please accept answers to your questions too, especially if they have single, high-scoring de facto answers.

Also a problem: accepting an answer that doesn't address the essential question.

Accepting a "bad" answer is not a huge problem, because de facto answers can still be voted up. If the question is good, an answer is good, and people are voting, I'm convinced the better answer will prevail. We just need to make sure at least one of the answers is good, and that people are voting!

Although up-votes are self-explanatory, please add a comment to explain your down-vote.

Keep in mind, all, that other sites very frequently use their meta for statements, and not always for direct questions!
